GCP Custom Connector
Trying to setup a custom connector for Autodesk to utilize the ACC/BIM360 Issue post.
I'm not a developer so even the most seemingly simple things will take a bit for me to decipher.
Here's what I think needs to happen:

First I need to set up Oauth?
I need to setup custom Connector to AD, but will this just generic and that's why it says Public URL?
Once the AD Custom Connector is validated I should be able to use task REST endpoint to create an issue?

Does anyone have any advice and or examples of this type of scenario?
It doesn't have to be for AD but maybe another Custom connection using GCP?

Unless you are interested in no code tools like Power Automate, where we have some plugins like this one, to create a custom connector will require some developer skills.
If you are interested in following the dev part, you should start with basic tutorials and once mastered, you will be able to bend it to your need. By the way, there are also free 101 trainings.
